# Do anarchists want to eliminate all the power or only juridical one?

Tags: political-philosophy, society, anarchism

I often see as a criticism of anarchism that power has a natural occurrence. It's impossible to eliminate power. There will always be an authority.

However, I always thought that the total elimination of power is not the purpose of anarchists. I thought that only coercive power should be eliminated in the view of anarchists. It is very obvious that even among friends there are those who usually suggest something and those who accept or reject it, where we can say the first has greater power. In masses, those who can produce better arguments will be leaders and the others their followers. Leaders have greater power than followers. It is so obvious that this kind of power is inherent to humanity, because it arises from individual differences.

But all of this power that I described is not coercive. If a friend asks you to go hiking, you can refuse. You can always reject anything the leader says. But when the government says "You cannot use drugs, otherwise we'll imprison you", it is impossible to say "No". Government does not recognize "No". Therefore, it is coercive by definition.

So, do anarchists really want to eliminate all power, even leadership, which is implausible, or only eliminate juridical power?

Comment: Should we be asking which anarchists believe what?  I doubt they all agree.

Comment: @DavidThornley, I mean anarchism is ideology of what.

Comment: a lot of anarchists consider themselves anti-ideology don't they @rus9384

Comment: @user3293056, it's self-deception. Like the rule "No rules" is a rule, anti-ideology also is an ideology.

Comment: Power and authority are different concepts. Authority can bring power but power does not bring authority - only *force majeure*. Authority is the right to make decisions which others are legally or morally obliged (not forced) to obey. You don't need to mention authority; your whole question centres on coercive power. You are right, of course, that anarchism does not reject power but only coercive power.

Comment: Its not a question of power being eliminated but how power is organised and distributed.

Comment: @rus9384 Your government example, you can say no. The result is you do drugs and go to prison. Your hiking example, you can say no. The result is you don't go hiking and your friend reacts negatively. I don't see a fundamental difference. You are still capable of saying no and dealing with the consequences of each.

Comment: @Onyz, but if people reject to befriend you, they are not forcing you. But the government forces people. When goverment collects a tax it's not much more different when a criminal organization takes money from you. Indeed, a criminal organization can even protect you from being "taxated" by other criminal organizations. When policemen break open doors it's not much different than if non-policemen do it. But policemen have some kind of document that "proves" they are policemen and government has written laws which "justify" what is right.BTW, criminals also can have their unwritten laws.

Comment: @rus9384 As you already said yourself, the government is not forcing you, they are giving you a choice. Abide by the laws or go to jail. Just like how a friend is giving you a hypothetical choice- go hiking with me or don't be my friend anymore.

Comment: @Onyz, but why does government pretend it have a power over me? Who gave it power? By right of the powerful? A government can ban certain type of food, for example, would it be right? A friend, on the other side, hardly can prohibit (if you do it you will be beaten, jailed, killed, etc.) you eating any kind of food. Actually, given choice, of course, is a false dichotomy. Strong people do not go to jail - they win or die.

Comment: @rus9384 Every other thing in existence has some power over you by merit of being part of existence. The wind can knock you over. The ocean can drown you. Human beings can imprison or starve you. All of your actions (conscious or not) lead towards making choices in a limited list of options. This does not change in an Anarchy. It would only be worse. Rather than government imposing arbitrary rules that are inherited from the collective historical will of the general populace, you'd be enslaved by the most well-armed of your neighbors.

Comment: @Onyz, there are two types of people: those who believe in right of the powerful and those who believe in right of the rational. First should not and cannot be a part of anarchic society. Rational people do not want to imprison anyone who disagrees with them. "you'd be enslaved by the most well-armed of your neighbors" - this is exactly a paradigm of the first type of people. For example, I hear for other people reasons, this is what makes me rational. And rational people do not need to be forced by threat and fear.

Comment: @Onyz, and, btw, the government does not hear "No" because "There is a law saying X". You cannot argue the law is unfair and being heard, unless you are a legislator. Well, not in current societies, even the most liberal ones. So, you will just be imprisoned without hearing for counterarguments. When discussing something with friends you can argue for something and being heard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82467/discussion-between-onyz-and-rus9384).

Comment: Are you asking about their stated goal or their actual goal?

Answer (score 1):

**The goal of anarchism**

Anarchism envisages a post-state society of autonomous individuals and of voluntary, non-coercive social aggregates (such as communes and co-operatives).

There is scope for government in the sense of a co-ordinating body but this itself will be a voluntary, non-coercive social aggregate. **A govermment can have a juridical function** : to promulgate, administer, and to determine breaches of laws and to settle disputes about the interpretation of laws. But in the exercise of this function, no coercion is present or is permitted.

**No force or coercion**

An anarchist society cannot accommodate power in the sense of force or coercion.

Force : A has the power of force over B when A gets (or can get) B to do X regardless of B's volition (e.g. A controls or can control B by physical superiority - 'brute force')

Coercion : A has coercive power over B when A gets (or can get) B to do X by threat (e.g. A threatens to make B worse off relative to some baseline if B does not do X : lots of conditions have to be added such as that A must have certain motives, intentions and beliefs, else what appears to be a threat is not actually so, also B must believe that A's threat is credible and must do X because of A's threat and not because s/he was going to do X anyway, plus the 'worse off' must refer to a state of affairs that B considers not trivial but seriously detrimental to his or her interests)

**Forms of power**

> However, I always thought that the total elimination of power is not the purpose of anarchists.

That's dead right.

To remove **force** and **coercion** is not to exclude **power** from society. Without force or coercion I can still exercise power over you by the use of **persuasion** or **manipulation** or by **charisma** or **strength of personality**. To suppose that such elements could all be removed from an anarchist society appears excessively optimistic. There is also the power of **public opinion** - the serpent in the anarchist garden as it has been called.

---

Bibliography

Alan Wertheimer, Coercion (Studies in Moral, Political and Legal Philosophy), ISBN 10: 0691077592 / ISBN 13: 9780691077598
Published by Princeton Univ Press, 1988.

Robert Nozick, 'Coercion', White Morgenbesser (ed.), Philosophy, Science, and Method: Essays in Honor of Ernest Nagel. St Martin's Press. pp. 440--72 (1969).

David E. Apter & James Joll ed., Anarchism Today (Studies in comparative politics), ISBN 10: 0333120418 / ISBN 13: 9780333120415
Published by Macmillan, 1971.

I am unable to reference the 'serpent' quote : apologies.

Comment: that's really more of a bibliography

Answer (score 0):

One of the best approaches to this question is [In Defense of Anarchism](https://theanarchistlibrary.org/library/robert-paul-wolff-in-defense-of-anarchism)
since it deals with 'legitimacy' (or not) of government and the difficulties of 100% agreement in every single decision (therefore coercion-free at all times). Since there will not be 100% agreement, some kind of coercion will always exist in a society with boundaries. I'm setting aside the off-grid, outlaw of old, since law now seems to stretch into the farthest corners of a given nation-state.

However, I believe the secondary question, 'coercion about what' is also very important. Vanilla vs. chocolate isn't too dire, but important decisions (except Brexit apparently!) usually require a supermajority of 66% or 75% on the given question. There will always be a '[tyranny of the majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority)' problem lurking somewhere, when people try to do things together.

Incidentally, for those that don't go right through Wolff's book, he was interested in electronic solutions to voting, well before internet access became widespread.

Comment: Majority of important questions are solved without voting. People solving these questions already have been voted by people and, therefore, their decisions are matching people intentions. The idea is as absurd as it sounds. But politics are not about voting - they are about discussion, those who reduce politics to voting are making a great mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No Gods No Masters anthology p382

[image]

I don't think anarchists want to do away entirely with the judicial process, though at least some would want to do away with prisons. The idea seems to be more about returning its powers to a stateless people or working class.

Answer (score 0):

I can identify three levels of sophistication among anarchists:

First are those who, like teenagers, reject all forms of authority or coercion; these would imagine a world where no one has authority over another.

A little more sophisticated would be anarchists who have lost faith in the government and even the constitution. Here the aim is to break down government to the point that a new regime is required. The form of government, in the new regime, may or may not feature in their plans.

Lastly would be those who realize that government grows organically from simple voluntary authority, and that any regime change will inevitably lead to a similar status quo. there aim is not to break down but to challenge.

So to answer the question for each: 1. All, 2. It depends, 3. No

Comment: Well, the thing is to create a society where people are not willing to obey others, and to create economics where it is possible not to obey and still have means to live (in current a policeman must obey otherwise [s]he just can him/herself be punished regardless of what the commands are). Indeed, such a society is non-universal as not all people are born with feeling of independence (but they don't want anarchy either, so let they stay where they want). So, it's unclear what do you mean by regime then.

Comment: @rus9384 'Regime' would be the government of the day, the institutions and people who have the authority and power to coerce. I.e. anarchists stand opposed to the regime.

Comment: And who will raise it? I have not seen any revolution of anarchisrs (neither successful non-revolutionary activity) to support this claim.

Comment: If anarchists were to raise a government? It would dissolve before it materializes. No, from inside an existing regime, anarchists will have an 'attitude' or 'intent' as described above. Maybe the third variety of anarchists have _done_ something like raise awareness or sway public opinion on a _particular_ issue.

Comment: Also, "or" questions cannot be answered in "yes/no" manner. So, under "no" I think you meant "only juridical one". Actually anarchists are quite rare to actually bring a revolution. Therefore they can only rely on other groups, like communists before 1917 year revolution in Russian Empire (which was a huge mistake because they after all were stabbed in their backs). This probably means revolution is not a way and only way is to affect the government (which unfortunately many anarchists claim to be unanarchic, maybe because majority belongs to the first group).

Comment: @rus9384 No means neither. That is the most sophisticated anarchists will try to, as you say, "affect the government" but not break it down.